# Yii: Why does this query take 15 seconds?

Tags: mysql, yii

I am using `Yii MCV` with multiple `dbs`.

Why does it take 15 seconds to run this code?

How to improve?

I switch the `db connection` using a `server_id` integer value.

This is the `class` that switches the db connection.

```
class VillageSlaveM extends VillageM {

    const UNVERIFIED = 0;
    const VERIFIED = 1;

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public static $server_id;
    public static $slave_db;

    public function getDbConnection() {
        self::$slave_db = Yii::app()->dbx;
        if (self::$slave_db instanceof CDbConnection) {
            self::$slave_db->active = false;
            $config = require(Yii::app()->getBasePath() . '/config/main.php');
            $connectionString = $config['components']['dbx']['connectionString'];
            self::$slave_db->connectionString = sprintf($connectionString, self::$server_id);
            self::$slave_db->setActive(true);
            return self::$slave_db;
        }
        else
            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii', 'Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
    }

}
```

This is the code that needs 15 seconds to execute, dont know why so much.

It selects the one village that has the oldest `last_update_resource` timestamp value.

I have set indexes for all the db table fields involved.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = 'last_update_resource <= ' . ($time_start - 60 * 60 * 8);
        $criteria->order = 'last_update_resource asc';
        $criteria->limit = 1;

        VillageSlaveM::$server_id = $world_id;
        $start_x = time();
        $model_village = VillageSlaveM::model()->findByAttributes(array('map_type_id' => VillageM::$map_type_id['village'], 'status' => VillageM::ACTIVE), $criteria);
        $stop_x = time();
        $msg[] = 'start_x: ' . ($stop_x - $start_x);
```

ps: after this code runs, i have much more complex queries and they run instantly;

Comment: Probably your DB server is far away from you geographically?

Comment: Check the query in your logs, and run an EXPLAIN query to see what's going on. `EXPLAIN SELECT ....`

Comment: it seems that someone has deleted the indexes; ty davey